# How to decode strings that have special UTF-8 characters hex encoded in a pyspark dataframe

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a pyspark DataFrame like the one bellow, where the special characters have been hex encoded.

```
+--------------------+
|item_name           |
+--------------------+
|Jogador n\xBA 10    |
|Camisa N\xB0 9      |
|Uniforme M\xE9dio   |
+--------------------+
```

And I need to decode it to UTF-8 chars, like this:

```
+--------------------+
|item_name           |
+--------------------+
|Jogador nº 10       |
|Camisa N° 9         |
|Uniforme Médio      |
+--------------------+
```

Pyspark decode function makes no difference:

```
df.withColumn('test', decode(col('item_name'),'UTF-8')).show()

+--------------------+--------------------+
|item_name           |test                |
+--------------------+--------------------+
|Jogador n\xBA 10    |Jogador n\xBA 10    |
|Camisa N\xB0 9      |Camisa N\xB0 9      |
|Uniforme M\xE9dio   |Uniforme M\xE9dio   |
+--------------------+--------------------+
```

Comment: `u"º".encode("utf-8")` is `'\xc2\xba"` not `'\xba'` - are your sure your special characters are encoded correctly?

Comment: Following up on my previous comment, `spark.sql("select DECODE('\xc2\xb0', 'UTF-8') AS decoded").show()` produces the correct output (`°` as in your second row) whereas `spark.sql("select DECODE('\xb0', 'UTF-8') AS decoded").show()` does not work.

Comment: @pault, I don't know why the encoding returns this extra "\xc2" but the other way around decoding \xBA will raise correct char: chr(0xBA) = 'º'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pyspark will not decode correctly if the hex vales are preceded by double backslashes (ex: \\xBA instead of \xBA).

Using "take(3)" instead of "show()" showed that in fact there was a second backslash:

```
[Row(item_name='Jogador n\\xBA 10'),
 Row(item_name='Camisa N\\xB0 9'),
 Row(item_name='Uniforme M\\xE9dio')]
```

To solve this I created a UDF to decode using "unicode-escape" method:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
import pyspark.sql.types as T
my_udf = F.udf(lambda x: x.encode().decode('unicode-escape'),T.StringType())
df.withColumn('test', my_udf('item_name')).show()
+------------------+---------------+
|         item_name|           test|
+------------------+---------------+
|  Jogador n\xBA 10|  Jogador nº 10|
|    Camisa N\xB0 9|    Camisa N° 9|
| Uniforme M\xE9dio| Uniforme Médio|
+------------------+---------------+
```